# Am I connecting to internet when using MAPI in Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation

When I use MAPI in Python, like so:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Am I actually connecting to the internet for this to work? Since there are no credentials being passed in, I am guessing everything is happening locally? How does this work behind the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with a local data, i.e. Outlook (client MAPI subsystem).

In your sample code Outlook is just automated. To be precise, a new Outlook `Application` instance is created in the code and then a `Session` instanced is acquired by calling the [Application.GetNamespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.getnamespace) method. The `GetNameSpace` method is functionally equivalent to the `Session` property.

If you don't use the `Logon` method the default mail profile is used. And you don't connect to any service, everything is happening locally unless a non-cached mode of connecting to the Exchange server is used in Outlook.

You can use the [SyncObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject) if you need to synchronize the cached data in Outlook. A `Send\Receive` group lets users configure different synchronization scenarios, selecting which folders and which filters apply.